# Next.js 13.4.4 no se carga si existe un server action y está presente el middleware

Tags: nextjs

Tengo un formulario "use client" con una función de acción "server side".
Cuando el middleware actúa en la ruta de ese formulario, la aplicación falla al renderizar con este error.

[image: Error message]

Formulario en el lado del cliente (page.jsx):

```javascript
"use client";
import {
  Container,
  Avatar,
  Button,
  CssBaseline,
  TextField,
  FormControlLabel,
  Checkbox,
  Link,
  Grid,
  Box,
  Typography,
} from 'components/mui';
import { performSubmit } from './formSubmit';

export const SignInSide = () => {
  
  const action = async (e) => {
    await performSubmit(e);
  };

  return (
    // Contenido del formulario...
    <Box component={"form"} action={action}  noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }} method={"null"}>
  );
};

SignInSide.needAuth = false;

export default SignInSide;
```

Acción en el lado del servidor (performSubmit.js):

```javascript
"use server";
export async function performSubmit(formData) {
  console.log({
    email: formData.get('email'),
    password: formData.get('password'),
  });
};
```

Middleware (middleware.js):

```javascript
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { needAuth as _needAuth } from "./lib/needAuth";
import { AUTH } from 'routes';

export const config = { matcher: ["/auth"] }

export async function middleware(request) {
  const needAuth = await _needAuth(request);
  console.log(request.url);

  if (needAuth) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('AUTH', request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

El componente "components/mui" solo agrega "use client" a todos los componentes de Material UI.

Si elimino la acción, la aplicación funciona.

Si elimino el middleware (o omito esa página en el matcher), la aplicación funciona.

Lo que busco es poder tener formularios protegidos por el middleware, funcionando con acciones en de servidor.

En el ejemplo, en el matcher, estoy utilizando "auth" unicamente y se que eso no tiene sentido, pero la idea es poder tener otro formulario detrás del middleware.